# Get discount percentage in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have line of code where I try to get discounted price in percentage but it returns opposite.

```
{{((product.newprice/product.price)*100).toFixed(0)}}%
```

This supposed to return `3%` for instance but it returns `97%` instead. I've tried to move codes around to fix it but no luck.

## Example

```
price = 25.499.000
newprice = 24.750.000

result should be: 3% discount
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math is wrong. The discount is the original price minus the sale price, so your equation should be `((product.price - product.newprice)/product.price)*100`. Note that this will give you negative discounts if the new price is ever higher than the original.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most Easiest Way to caculate discount percentage is -

```
 {{100-((item.price/item.mrp)*100) }}
```

and in your Case -

```
{{100-((product.newprice/product.price)*100) }}
```

or else in Angular you can Use Pipe

```
{{((product.price-product-newprice)/product.price) |percent }}
```